# Google places types to find Xtreme sports

Tags: google-places-api

Why the google places types are so limited?, I looking places where to practice extreme sports(i.e. rafting,paragliding,surf) and are not show in the two permitted Lists,  and also  I can not add this to the lists, somebody could help me?, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try performing a Places API Search Request with the `keyword` parameter instead of `types` parameter. This is often successful when searching for types of places that are not in the types list.

e.g.

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&sensor=false&keyword=paragliding&location=37.3943,-122.151&radius=50000

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/):

> The `keyword` parameter is matched against all content that Google has
>   indexed for this Place, including but not limited to name, type, and
>   address, as well as customer reviews and other third-party content.