# Google Places API - adding new types, Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-places-api

When I perform a general search of farmers markets on Google maps on my desktop, it shows all of the markets. But farmers markets is not listed as an available "type" in the Google Places API. Is there a way to add types that are not specifically listed in the API? If not available using the Places API, could I create a separate class that would be incorporated into Google Maps that captures all the specific locations I'm wanting to provide to the user of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the below [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999194/google-places-types-to-find-xtreme-sports), it appears that rather than using one of the specific "types" listed in Google Places, you can instead you "keyword" to limit your search to particular locations that are not included in the Google Places type categories. Thanks to this thread which helped me find this answer.